# How to improve switch case that returns true/false or throw an exception?

Tags: java, list, exception, switch-statement, contains

Given the following code:

```
private boolean isBlahTrue(final BigDecimal status) {

        switch (status.intValue()) {

            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 3:
                return true;

            case 5:
            case 6:
            case 7:
                return false;

            default:
                throw new MyAppRuntimeException("Status unknown!");
        }
    }
```

My question is: Is this good or bad practice?

Logic is:

```
1, 2, 3  --> true
5, 6, 7  --> false
```

But anyway one could think about that a simple IF would do the stuff too, like

```
if (1,2,3) {true}, else {false}
```

.

But then I would not check if the status is e.g. 4 (which must lead to an exception).

I tried some solutions, like contains, but the code doesn't improve.

Any ideas that I could try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using a Map in this case.

something like

```
Map<Integer, Boolean> statusChecker = new HashMap<>();
statusChecker.put(1, true);
statusChecker.put(2, true);
... 
statusChecker.put(5, false);
...
```

Now you can do the checking

```
if(!statusChecker.contains(status)) {
   throw RuntimeException("invalid status");
} else {
   return statusChecker.get(status);
}
```

Comment: that seems to be a good input because one could make the map final and static, too... I will try it, thx

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with what you already have. But if you are using Java12 or higher you can make use of the switch expressions introduced in Java 12:

```
private boolean isBlahTrue(final BigDecimal status) {
    return switch (status.intValue()){
        case 1, 2, 3 -> true;
        case 5, 6, 7 -> false;
        default -> throw new MyAppRuntimeException("Status unknown!");
    };
}
```

Comment: true, thx, but unfortunately java 11 at the moment :-)